# Database Access denied on Laravel in Production

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, hosting

I'm trying to publish my Laravel 5.8 app on production hosting. I've uploaded the files and have made the changes in .env file. But still while accessing my application., it throws error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO)

Below is my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST= ip
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=secret
DB_USERNAME='secret'
DB_PASSWORD='secret'
```

I have also made changes in database.php:

```php
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'secret'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env(‘DB_DATABASE', 'secret'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'secret'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSNORD', 'secret'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO: :I'IYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env( 'MYSQL_ATTR_SS L_CA' ),
    ]) : [],
},
```

Comment: Use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` then comment results.

Comment: run `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

then

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=secret   //enter your right databse name
DB_USERNAME=secret  //please check your username
DB_PASSWORD=secret  //please check your password
```

or

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=secret  //enter your right databse name
DB_USERNAME=root     //please check your username
DB_PASSWORD=enter your correct password //please check your password
```

**change your databse.php**

```
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env(‘DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSNORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO: :I'IYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env( 'MYSQL_ATTR_SS L_CA' ),
    ]) : [],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As a comment suggest, use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`, but also, same error occurs to me and the problem was the Laravel project cache: just use `php artisan config:cache` to re-cache the files, or just delete all the files inside the bootstrap/cache folder